# Convert from windows-1252 to utf-8 in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, decoding, windows-1252

I want to convert from windows-1252 to utf-8 in python, I wrote this code:

```
def encode(input_file, output_file):
        f = open(input_file, "r")
        data = f.read()
        f.close()

        # Convert from Windows-1252 to UTF-8
        encoded = data.encode('Windows-1252').decode('utf-8')
        with safe_open_w(output_file) as f:
            f.write(encoded)
```

but I have this error:

```
encoded = data.encode('Windows-1252').decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 5653: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried to convert a html with this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

Comment: If you're reading and writing text files, just pass the encoding as parameter when reading and writing:`f = open(input_file, "r", encoding='Windows-1252')` and `with safe_open_w(output_file, encoding='utf8') as f:`

Answer (score 9):

You are converting the wrong way. You want to *decode* from cp1252 and then *encode* into UTF-8. But the latter isn't really necessary; Python already does it for you.

When you *decode* something, the input should be `bytes` and the result is a Python string. Writing a string to a file already implicitly converts it, and you can actually do the same for reading, too, by specifying an encoding.

Additionally, reading the entire file into memory is inelegant and wasteful.

```py
with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as inp,\
        open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outp:
    for line in inp:
        outp.write(line)
```

Comment: I'm guessing your real file is double or triple encoded. Without seeing the actual bytes we can't really tell. Maybe see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors